# How to extract every possible values of python Dict's values to list

Tags: python

```
DICTA={'bw':['BW','VW'],'b':['BB','VV'],'a':['AA']}
DICTB={'yn':['$YN','$YNN'],'ye':['$YE','A$Y'],'y':['Y$']}
```

How to extract every possible values of that 2 Dict to

```
["BWYN","VWYN","BBYN","VVYN","AAYN","BWYNN","VWYNN","BBYNN","VVYNN","AAYNN",
"BWYE","VWYE","BBYE","VVYE","AAYE","ABWY","AVWY","ABBY","AVVY","AAAY",
"YBW","YVW","YBB","YVV","YAA"]
```

PS: Order does not matter

PPS: Not homework, but like to know how it can be implemented in efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many possible minor variants on the following fundamental theme:

```
print [y.replace('$', x)
  for y in (v for y in DICTB.values() for v in y)
  for x in (v for y in DICTA.values() for v in y)
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to go with `itertools` myself, but essentially the same as Alex's solution:

```
from itertools import product

[
    y.replace('$', x)
    for (x, y) in product(sum(DICTA.values(), []), sum(DICTB.values(), []))
]
```